# Upgrade Linux Packages one by one

Tags: linux, upgrade, apt, parrot-os

How can I Upgrade Linux Packages one by one instead of downloading multiple Packages at once?
[Linux Terminal Upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXIpu.png)
As in the above image, apt is downloading multiple Packages at once. I would like to download them one by one when I use  `sudo apt full-upgrade` Since my Internet is too slow and download usually cancel as request Timeouts.

Comment: Duplicate on our sister site: [How can I tell `apt-get update` to download only one file at a time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331045/53467)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Duplicates https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331045/53467